# Use makeindex with pandoc while creating a PDF from a Markdown file

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I have got a `markdown file` and like to convert it to `pdf`. I need an index. For this I found [makeindx](https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Makeidx.html)

I am using this command for creating a pdf from a markdown file:

```
pandoc "test.md" \
--from markdown --to latex \
--toc \
--toc-depth=1 \
--include-in-header index.tex \
--include-in-header chapter_break.tex \
--include-in-header inline_code.tex \
--include-in-header bullet_style.tex \
--include-in-header pdf_properties.tex \
--highlight-style pygments.theme \
-V toc-title='Inhaltsverzeichnis' \
-V title='Mein Titel' \
-V author='Ich' \
-V book=true \
-V date="24. Mai 2021" \
-V classoption='oneside' \
--template ./eisvogel.latex \
--listings \
-o "test.pdf"
```

The template Eisvogel I found on [github](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template). I asked the question in an [issue](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/issues/243) here, too.

The file `index.tex` has this content:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
```

In my document I use

```
Installation\index{Installation}
```

and at the end

```
\printindex
```

Unfortunately, no index is printed.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit I found a temporarily solution:

First I create a *.latex.

```
    pandoc JoomlaEnPDF.en.md \
-o 1.en.tex \
--from markdown \
--template ./eisvogel.latex \
--listings \
--toc \
--toc-depth=1 \
-V toc-title="Content" \
--top-level-division="part" \
--number-sections \
```

Then I run the commands manually.

```
pdflatex 1.en.tex
pdflatex 1.en.tex

makeindex 1.en.idx

cat  ./1.en.ind  >> JoomlaEnPDF.en.md
```

Then I create the pdf

```
pandoc JoomlaEnPDF.en.md \
-o 1.en.pdf \
--from markdown \
--template ./eisvogel.latex \
--listings \
--toc \
--toc-depth=1 \
-V toc-title="Table of Contents" \
--top-level-division="part" \
--number-sections \
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: See the temporarily solution I added to my question.